# How can I extend a width of a specific td to the full width of the table

Tags: css, row, width, cell

I have a table made fully on a WP woocommerce plugin. All data in a table is added with a products from a store and works automatically, so I hope it's possible not to touch the html of the table(However, I can add a part of any html code to the cell as a new row of the cell.

I want every second row of the table to be a full width row, so the product image and the product description cover all empty columns on the right.

With this plugin I'm able to change CSS and JS and add classes to every element.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnoy4.png)

I tried to change the position to "absolute" and set up settings, so it covers the whole row

```
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: auto;
}
```

it works, but it covers the next row, and I want this row to be set between two rows.
The whole green block with a data is a div inside a td of a table row of the first column(structured by plugin).
Unfortunately, i'm not able to just add a row, i can add a row only inside the column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c46sy.png)

Update:
It is possible to make child rows with Woocommerce plugin in a few clicks

https://wcproducttable.com/documentation/child-row-facility

Answer (score 0):

The  tag has width attribute to control the width of a particular column. By assigning a numeric value to this attribute between 0 to 100 in terms of percentage. We can restrict the column width up to that much percentage of the table's total width.